# How we can Import Images from Evernote in iPhone sdk

Tags: ios, evernote

I am developing an app which is drawing tool project and we need to import image from evernote account into my app.

I am using below code to get note list. But i am not able to decode "data.bodyHash" NSData and image become nil. You can see in below code.

```
EvernoteSession *session = [EvernoteSession sharedSession];
EDAMNoteFilter* filter = [[EDAMNoteFilter alloc] initWithOrder:0 ascending:NO words:nil notebookGuid:nil tagGuids:nil timeZone:nil inactive:NO emphasized:nil];
[[EvernoteNoteStore noteStore] findNotesWithFilter:filter offset:0 maxNotes:100 success:^(EDAMNoteList *list) {
    for (EDAMNote *note in list.notes) {
        NSLog(@"Notes : %@",note.title);
        NSMutableArray *resources = note.resources;
        if (resources!=nil) {
            EDAMResource* resource = [resources objectAtIndex:0];
            EDAMData *data = resource.data;
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data.bodyHash];
            /// Image is nil
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that we can import image from Evernote ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible. There are steps you should take to achieve the desired result.

1) Ensure that your Evernote Application has full access to user's Evernote account to able to read existing notes (you can set this up when requesting Evernote API Key on https://dev.evernote.com )

2) Authenticate

```
[self.session authenticateWithViewController:self
                          preferRegistration:NO
                                  completion:^(NSError* authenticateError) {
  ...
}];
```

3) Find all notes

```
[self.session findNotesWithSearch:nil
                       inNotebook:nil
                          orScope:ENSessionSearchScopeAll
                        sortOrder:ENSessionSortOrderNormal
                       maxResults:255
                       completion:^(NSArray* findNotesResults,
                                    NSError* findNotesError) {
  ...
}];
```

4) Download each note

```
for (ENSessionFindNotesResult* result in findNotesResults) {
  [self.session downloadNote:result.noteRef
                    progress:NULL
                  completion:^(ENNote* note,
                               NSError* downloadNoteError) {
    ...
  }];
}
```

5) Get all images

```
for (ENResource* resource in note.resources) {
  if ([resource.mimeType hasPrefix:@"image"]) {
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:resource.data];
    ...
  }
}
```

You can check [sample project here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/930742/so/EvernoteTest.zip).
If you set consumer key and secret, after authentication you'll see similar console output:

```
2014-08-19 22:54:18.782 EvernoteTest[71234:60b] finding all notes..
2014-08-19 22:54:20.356 EvernoteTest[71234:60b] processing find notes results..
2014-08-19 22:54:21.294 EvernoteTest[71234:60b] getting images from note 'Just Image'
2014-08-19 22:54:21.294 EvernoteTest[71234:60b] >> image with size {600, 400}
2014-08-19 22:54:21.295 EvernoteTest[71234:60b] 
2014-08-19 22:54:21.720 EvernoteTest[71234:60b] getting images from note 'Getting Started'
2014-08-19 22:54:21.721 EvernoteTest[71234:60b] >> image with size {27, 27}
2014-08-19 22:54:21.721 EvernoteTest[71234:60b] >> image with size {215, 54}
2014-08-19 22:54:21.722 EvernoteTest[71234:60b] >> image with size {300, 300}
2014-08-19 22:54:21.722 EvernoteTest[71234:60b] >> image with size {27, 27}
2014-08-19 22:54:21.723 EvernoteTest[71234:60b] >> image with size {27, 27}
2014-08-19 22:54:21.723 EvernoteTest[71234:60b] >> image with size {27, 27}
2014-08-19 22:54:21.724 EvernoteTest[71234:60b] >> image with size {27, 27}
2014-08-19 22:54:21.724 EvernoteTest[71234:60b] >> image with size {27, 27}
2014-08-19 22:54:21.725 EvernoteTest[71234:60b] >> image with size {27, 27}
2014-08-19 22:54:21.725 EvernoteTest[71234:60b] 
2014-08-19 22:54:22.179 EvernoteTest[71234:60b] getting images from note 'Another Image'
2014-08-19 22:54:22.180 EvernoteTest[71234:60b] >> image with size {685, 514}
2014-08-19 22:54:22.180 EvernoteTest[71234:60b]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the step by step description, I have found images from below function:
- (void)getResourceWithGUID:(NSString*)resourceGUID {
    [[EvernoteNoteStore noteStore] getResourceWithGuid:resourceGUID withData:YES withRecognition:NO withAttributes:YES withAlternateDate:NO success:^(EDAMResource *resource) {
        NSData* fileContent = resource.data.body;
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:fileContent];
        }
       
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
    }];
}